# Javascript function seems to always receive the same input

Tags: javascript, html

I'm fighting for hours with this piece of code. No matter what choice I make, the output is always as if I had chosen the first line (set17, gpio17 and whatever is in the first combo box).

I've tried to change the single quotes for double quotes, tried different browsers, and defined different ajaxFunctions for each line, but the result is always the same.

The expected result is, for instance, the alert box with the values of the GPIO24 line when the combo box of it is changed.

Can anyone with a fresher mind tell me what am I doing wrong?

By the way, is there any way to pass the $item and $action variables to "document.getElementById" without the need to create the text boxes?

Thanks in advance

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  xml:lang="en">
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
function ajaxFunction(){
var action = document.getElementById('action');
var item = document.getElementById('item');
var value = document.getElementById('value');
alert("You entered: " + " " + action.value + " " + value.value + " " + item.value )


}
</script>


<center><b>AJAX TEST PAGE</b><br/><br/><table border="1"><tr>

<td>gpio17</td><td> Sensor Wireless #3 <td>
<form name='gpio17'>
<select id='value' onchange='ajaxFunction()'>
<option value= value_option_1> value_option_1</option>
<option value='value-option_1'>Option_1_display</option>
<option value='value-option_2'>Option_2_display</option>
<option value='value-option_3'>Option_3_display</option>
</select><td>
<input type='text' id='action' value='set17' /> <br />
<input type='text' id='item' value='gpio17' /></td></form></td></tr><tr>

<td>gpio23</td><td> Sensor Wireless #2<td>
<form name='gpio23'>
<select id='value' onchange='ajaxFunction()'>
<option value= value_option_2> value_option_2</option>
<option value='value-option_1'>Option_1_display</option>
<option value='value-option_2'>Option_2_display</option>
<option value='value-option_3'>Option_3_display</option>
</select><td>
<input type='text' id='action' value='set23' /> <br />
<input type='text' id='item' value='gpio23' /></td></form></td></tr><tr>

<td>gpio24</td><td> Sensor Wireless #1<td>
<form name='gpio24'>
<select id='value' onchange='ajaxFunction()'>
<option value= value_option_1> value_option_1</option>
<option value='value-option_1'>Option_1_display</option>
<option value='value-option_2'>Option_2_display</option>
<option value='value-option_3'>Option_3_display</option>
</select><td>
<input type='text' id='action' value='set24' /> <br />
<input type='text' id='item' value='gpio24' /></td></form></td></tr><tr>

<td>gpio25</td><td> Sensor Wireless #0
<td><form name='gpio25'>
<select id='value' onchange='ajaxFunction()'>
<option value= value_option_3> value_option_3</option>
<option value='value-option_1'>Option_1_display</option>
<option value='value-option_2'>Option_2_display</option>
<option value='value-option_3'>Option_3_display</option>
</select><td>
<input type='text' id='action' value='set25' /> <br />
<input type='text' id='item' value='gpio25' /></td></form></td></tr>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you have multiple elements with identical `id` property? It is supposed to be unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your html is invalid: the `id` attribute needs to be unique. When you use `document.getElementById()` with an id that is not unique you only get one element back (in most browsers it will be the first one).

You can pass a reference to the particular element that the event was triggered on like this:

```
<select id='makethisuniqueordeleteattributecompletelyifnotused'
        onchange='ajaxFunction(this)'>
```

> *" is there any way to pass the $item and $action variables to "document.getElementById" without the need to create the text boxes?"*

Yes. Since they are just string values you can do this:

```
<select id='makethisuniqueordeleteattributecompletelyifnotused'
        onchange='ajaxFunction(this,"set17","gpio17")'>
```

Then you can change your function to accept these values as follows:

```
function ajaxFunction(el, action, item){
    // selected value of select element in question:
    var value = el.value;
    alert("You entered: " + " " + value + " " + action + " " + item );
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8ACHe/